# Where to see the date for when a k8s version in azure "expires" (is no available for an upgrade)?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I currently have a 1.15.5 K8s cluster hosted in azure that I will soon look into upgrading. I can see this should still be possible:

```
$ az aks get-upgrades --resource-group my-cluster --name my-cluster --output table
Name     ResourceGroup    MasterVersion    Upgrades
-------  ---------------  ---------------  ----------------
default  my-cluster  1.15.5           1.16.13, 1.16.15
```

But going forward where do I find some public documentation for the exact date a specific version of k8s will no longer be valid for an upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the information you are looking for in [Supported Kubernetes versions in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions).

From the docs:

> AKS publishes a pre-announcement with the planned date of a new
> version release and respective old version deprecation on the [AKS
> Release notes](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/releases) at least 30 days prior to removal.

[image]

[For the past release history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes#History).

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/4b0026a83f0ce0f428a1cdd50523bd50dc2f13ff/CHANGELOG.md).

To find out which versions are currently available for your subscription and region, use the az aks get-versions command.

```
 az aks get-versions --location eastus --output table
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Ok so I cannot see the exact date for when 1.15.5 will be "upgrade invalidated"? I can only expect to see a notification in github at least 30 days before I can no longer upgrade?

Comment: From docs : `When a new minor version is introduced, the oldest minor version and patch releases supported are deprecated and removed. When AKS releases 1.18.*, it means that all the 1.15.* versions will be removed and will be out of support in 30 days.`  Yes, you are correct.. this is not a very comfortable way to monitor the depreciation version but as much as I can tell this is the only way.

Comment: Seems very strange that I cannot get an exact date for when it will no longer be possible to upgrade 1.15.5. The tables/links you provide above does not contain any information on this - just what can currently be installed/upgraded. But I am asking about a date for when it will no longer be possible to upgrade a specific version.

Comment: This is the information I found.. in case you find the exact date a version getting deprecated I would love to know that as well..